# Filtering a dynamic dropdown does not work on mobile unit (jQuery Mobile)

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, mobile

I have a page with two types of listed content. One is listed as a navigable list, and one is presented in a dropdown.

Both are built dynamically and injected into the DOM at runtime.

I have added a search field to both listings. On a desktop client (Chrome) it works fine to filter both the dropdown and the regular listing, by using this field.

But when i use a mobile unit (tried Android/IOS) only the first filtering works, the one that should filter the dropdown does not work on a mobile unit. Nothing happens in the list when i open it...

What gives?

Code for first dropdown (works on both desktop browser and mobile):

```
<form>
   <input data-type="search" id="searchForRound" data-clear-btn="false">
</form>

<div data-role="content" id="roundslist" data-filter="true" data-input="#searchForRound">
   <!-- /content -->
</div>
```

Code for second dropdown acting on a dropdown selector (working ONLY in desktop browser, not in mobile):

```
<form>
   <input data-type="search" id="searchForLocation" data-clear-btn="false">
</form>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="savefollowup" name="savefollowup"  action="" method="POST">
   <label for="wo_location">Placering:</label>
   <select id="wo_location" name="wo_location" data-filter="true" data-input="#searchForLocation">
      <!-- Dynamic insert here, based on selected department -->
   </select>
```

Any suggestions as to why this does not work on the mobile units?

Comment: filterable widget adds `ui-screen-hidden` class to _hide_ them. On mobile browsers, it is not possible to _hide_ `display: none;`. Instead, _disable_ unwanted options. https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/6682 demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/dzsanf1k/

Comment: I tried to add the fix, and it fixed a different bug i had with width being corrupted on the list... So thank you for that! But unfortunately it did not solve the problem of the list not refreshing at all on a mobile unit.

Now it works flawless on desktop browsers, but on mobile units it just displays the full list everytime.

Comment: You're welcome. What do you by "_t did not solve the problem of the list not refreshing at all on a mobile unit_"? please provide more details.

Comment: When opening the list after entering a filter it works great on desktop browser in testing.

If i try on a mobile unit, it just opens the entire list still... Even after entering a filter. Tested on Android phone. Same server used.

Comment: you update second `select` based on first `select`? can you setup a fiddle?

Comment: No. They're completely separate. But they are both based on data pushed into the DOM. 

Tried to lift that part out and use hardcoded values, but the issues remain for the dropdown. It does not filter at all on mobile devices (Chrome, Safari). 

Also, there is an issue still remaining in desktop, where sometimes, certain data causes the dropdown content to be entirerly hidden but only in Chrome and IE, not in Firefox. In Firefox everything works... Had the same problems with the load spinner earlier in this project... 

I like jQuery but these inconsistencies drive me nuts!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61976/discussion-between-omar-and-richard-eriksson).

Comment: Managed to fix the issues, using the code suggested by Omar above, but i had to place it on initial document loading, it wouldn't work anywhere else. Probably due to the page transitioning (using jQM single html/multipage-layout). Thanks! Now all seems well...